# Asynchronous image loading for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, asynchronous

I'm trying to get asynchronous image loading working in my app but apparently I just really suck, even when copying code! I've been following this tutorial: http://www.geekygoodness.com/2009/09/13/a-simple-cocoa-asynchronous-image-loader-class-to-use-in-your-iphone-app/

and I'm getting 3 errors in my .h file. My entire .h file from top to bottom looks like this:

```
//
//  GGImageLoader.h
//  
//
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol GGImageLoader 

// Asynchronous Image loading
@interface GGImageLoader : NSObject { // ERROR - "No type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'"

    NSURLConnection * connection;

    NSURL * url;

    NSMutableData * mutData;

    UIImage * image;

    id delegate;

}

@property ( nonatomic, retain ) UIImage * image;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)aURL;
- (void)setDelegate:(id)anObject;
- (void)load;

@end

@protocol GGImageLoaderProtocol // ERROR - "No type or storage class may be specified here before 'interface'"

@required
- (void)imageLoader:(GGImageLoader *)loader
       didLoadImage:(UIImage *)anImage;

@optional
- (void)imageLoader:(GGImageLoader *)loader
    didReceiveError:(NSError *)anError;

@end
//
```

The errors I get are written next to the code above, and the 3rd is "Method declaration not in @interface context".

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

what is `@protocol GGImageLoader` on top of the page. Remove that.

Comment: There is no reference of any such thing on the link you provided as well. Only 1 protocol should be defined which is correctly done at the end.

Comment: what do you mean by not causing the error. As far as I know there is no concept of an interface in a protocol

Comment: Thanks for the replies. When I created GGImageLoader.h `@protocol GGImageLoader` was already in there. If I remove it, i get 32 errors.

Comment: SO seems like when you created a new file, you specified it as a protocol ".h" file in Xcode. Never mind, this protocol definition is not required at all. A follow up question, do you have the "GGImageLoader.m" in-place and has included this ".h" header file?

Comment: @robin - I couldn't find the flip view app in xcode. Can you point me to some web link which has that code. Apple does list all sample code online. Also, can we move this conversation to some SO chat room instead. I don't want to hijack this thread for our discussion

Comment: I didn't actually make a GGImageLoader.m. I'm using the image loading in 4 views so I created the .h file then in the view I want to load it into, I added '#import "GGImageLoader.h"'

Comment: just put a ; after the @protocal statement and run it.

Comment: @hairyhi, its named under utility application.

Comment: @edhog- I think that's the reason it isn't working. To be sure, can you give a snippet of the ".m" file where you are using GGImageLoader.h to load image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `;` after the `@protocol GGImageLoader` at both the places

Answer (score 0):

Add `@end` after `@protocol GGImageLoader`